# networkextension does not import newer version

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3, networkextension

I'm trying to work with networkextension in xcode 10 ios12
basically, I have imported it and it supposed to be from ios12 which has an extra func ( startVPNTunnelwithOptions ) i can overide it.
but instead, xcode seems link it to older version. Now if I try to override it, xcode keeps telling me to use startVPNTunnel

```
Replace 'startVPNTunnelWithOptions(' with 'startVPNTunnel(options:
1. 'startVPNTunnelWithOptions' was obsoleted in Swift 3 (NetworkExtension.NEVPNConnection)
```

As above msg shows, xcode seems using swift3 instead of 4.2 or 5.

but I'm using latest xcode and macOS and I even set project to development target to 12.2 and in Swift lang I set to swift5

[image]

startVPNTunnelWithOptions method is in customized PacketTunnelProvider.m 
and i have a bridge header file to bridge it 
following is what's in bridge file

```
#import "../ConnectTunnel/PacketTunnelProvider.h"
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: this error `startVPNTunnelWithOptions' was obsoleted in Swift 3` means that the `startVPNTunnelWithOptions` method only works prior Swift 3, for Swift 3+ you need to use `startVPNTunnel(options:) method

Comment: hmmm are u sure it's obsolete?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnconnection/1406061-startvpntunnelwithoptions?language=objc

Comment: Could you upload the project somewhere so that we can see the issue? Is your codebase in Swift or objective-c as there is an ambiguity your screenshot shows Objective-C files and in the Question you are writing about Swift

Comment: Also have you checked your project Settings?? I mean Build Settings -> All and then filter Swift and check if nothing is Set for Swift3. Perhaps the NetworkExtension has an older target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)startVPNTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSObject *> *)options 
                   andReturnError:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

This method is available in objc and was obsoleted in swift 3
Objc doc link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnconnection/1406061-startvpntunnelwithoptions?language=objc

In swift 3+ the function was renamed to `func startVPNTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]? = nil) throws`

Swift doc link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnconnection/1406061-startvpntunnel